# Sitecore external database integration

Tags: database, sitecore, pipeline

What would be a good way, and good practice when "integrating" an external SQL database, in a Sitecore project.

The Sitecore project will get alot of its content from this external database, which is maintained elsewhere, and is constantly updated. (so copying the external database or syncing, is not really prefered, and we dont plan on enriching the data either)

Are there some method of defining some objects and "pipelines" between the Sitecore, and the external database (say without having to use, too many webservices)

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is create a custom Data Provider to connect to your external SQL database. This way you can expose the external data to Sitecore as if it were native data.

See [When to Implement Data Providers in the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/when-to-implement-data-providers-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) for more information.

Comment: "Custom Data Provider" that sounds exactly like the thing I need, and thanks for the links.

Comment: Hi Martijn, both the links are not working :-(. I know it's been a long time. By any chance could you please provide any updated references?

Comment: Hence the problem with link-only answers. I've fixed the link I could find a replacement for and put in a title in case Sitecore changes URLs again, and removed the other.

Answer (score 0):

When we implement architecture like this, we would use a search index (like solr) for maintaining state of the external database and keep enough content to display lists.

I would then request the external source for the display of an "article".
Sitecore would own the web application, url and all page rendering definitions.

If you want to use DMS you might want to extend this further into having some items for referencing elements